# Can I stream a Python pickle list, tuple, or other iterable data type?

Tags: python, streaming, ipython, pickle

I work with comma/tab-separated data files often that might look like this:

```
key1,1,2.02,hello,4
key2,3,4.01,goodbye,6
...
```

I might read and pre-process this in Python into a list of lists, like this:

```
[ [ key1, 1, 2.02, 'hello', 4 ], [ key2, 3, 4.01, 'goodbye', 6 ] ]
```

Sometimes, I like saving this list of lists as a pickle, since it preserves the different types of my entries. If the pickled file is big, though, it would be great to read this list of lists back in a streaming fashion.

In Python, to load a text file as a stream, I use the follwoing to print out each line:

```
with open( 'big_text_file.txt' ) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Can I do something similar for a Python list, i.e.:

```
import pickle
with open( 'big_pickled_list.pkl' ) as p:
    for entry in pickle.load_streaming( p ): # note: pickle.load_streaming doesn't exist
        print entry
```

Is there a pickle function like "load_streaming"?

Comment: what do you mean by "streaming"? what do you want "entry" to be? also note your code, as posted, is likely not doing what you intend. did you mean `for entry in pkl` instead of `for entry in p`?

Comment: I think by "streaming" he means iterating a pickle file as a sequence of pickles, the same way you can iterate a text file as a sequence of lines, as mata's answer does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This would work.

What is does however is unpickle one object from the file, and then print the rest of the file's content to `stdout`

What you could do is something like:

```
import cPickle
with open( 'big_pickled_list.pkl' ) as p:
    try:
        while True:
            print cPickle.load(p)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

That would unpickle all objects from the file until reaching EOF.

---

If you want something that works like `for line in f:`, you can wrap this up easily:

```
def unpickle_iter(file):
    try:
        while True:
             yield cPickle.load(file)
    except EOFError:
        raise StopIteration
```

Now you can just do this:

```
with open('big_pickled_list.pkl') as file:
    for item in unpickle_iter(file):
        # use item ...
```

Comment: Now combine your answer the [contextlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) decorator and you can do `with unpickle(filename):`

Comment: @drewk - You mean in case the iterator isn't fully consumed or an exception is raised while iterating... Yea, I missed that. But I don't think a `contextlib.contextmanager` would be very useful here, and much more complicated then the solution [originally suggested by abarnet](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17623631/2) of explicitly opening the file as context manager - so I'm reverting to that.

Comment: @mata Hmm, sorry, I don't think I was clear, so I edited my question. I usually have a list of lists as my pickled object, not a whole set of pickled objects. For a list of lists in big_pickled_list, your suggestion doesn't work. However, should I be storing objects in my pickle differently?

Comment: @mata -- actually, your method works if I store as my data not as a list of lists, but rather as one list after another. I've always done the former, and it has certain advantages (i.e. dumping an entire list of lists at once, or selecting certain entries with a list comprehension), but it might make more sense for me to start dumping multiple list objects.

Comment: @spadina - sorry i misunderstood your intention. I thought you had a file with multiple pickeled objects stored one after another - which, as you see, is possible to do, and makes sense to do if you have a large number of objects and only need one at a time. I thought that was your intention, avoiding to pull a large list of objects into memory all at once. otherwise you could just use `with open(file) as f: unpickled_stuff = pickle.load(f)` and then iterate normally outside the with block.

Comment: Using the EOFError like this seems dangerous, as you'll no longer get an exception if the file is corrupt.  The iteration will simply complete.  Any suggestions to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on a comment I made on the accepted solution, I recommend a loop more like this:

```
import cPickle
with open( 'big_pickled_list.pkl' ) as p:
    while p.peek(1):
        print cPickle.load(p)
```

This way you'll continue to get the EOFError exception if there is a corrupted object in the file.

For completeness:

```
def unpickle_iter(file):
    while file.peek(1):
        yield cPickle.load(file)
```

Comment: is there a particular way of dumping file in order to make it readable in that way? I just used `with open('list.p', 'wb') as p : pickle.dump(lst, p)` and it throws `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'peek'` under Python 2.7

Comment: I got it! my complete example is here: https://gist.github.com/marekyggdrasil/14bbb9e2ca91f9a1fad8495b5ac59354

Comment: The solution above works only if open is from the `io` module like so: `with io.open(big_pickled_list.pkl', 'wb') as p :` as @Marek suggested. I am leaving this for reference and search relevance.